# Can we get a set of Android devices to update/ sync at once?

Tags: sync, multiple-devices

Within the school where I work there is a mix of Android and Apple Tablets. We use Apple Configurator for the iPads and are wondering if there is a system out there which can do the same for the Android tablets?

We can either connect to them through the charging cabinet or over a wireless connection.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. We would prefer a free option, though prices aren't really a deal-breaker.